# Car lamp vs car light

Tags: word-usage

My son pointed my car's tail lamp and asked,

"What is this?"

**"This is car lamp."`**

What is the correct word to be use, car light or car lamp?

If the light is off. We call it lamp.

If the light is on. We call it light.

Was that right?

Is this car light?

[image: Car rear lamp cluster]

Is this car lamp?
[image: Car headlamp cluster]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always heard tail light, but tail lamp would be understandable. However, you need the "tail".  Otherwise, it could be the head light or a dashboard light or an interior light and it wouldn't be clear.

Comment: Headlight and taillight are usually one word (AmE).